# Improving set comparisons by hashing them (being overly clever..?)

Tags: c#, optimization, hash

After my last, failed, attempt at asking a question here I'm trying a more precise question this time:

What I have:

1. A huge dataset (finite, but I wasted days of multi-core processing time to compute it before...) of `ISet<Point>`.
2. A list of input values between 0 to 2<sup>n</sup>, n≤17

What I need:

3) A table of [1], [2] where I map every value of [2] to a value of [1]

The processing:

For this computation I have a formula, that takes a bit value (from [2]) and a set of positions (from [1]) and creates a new `ISet<Point>`. I need to find out which of the original set is equal to the resulting set (i.e. The "cell" in the table at "A7" might point to "B").

The naive way:

Compute the new `ISet<Point>` and use `.Contains(mySet)` or something similar on the list of values from [1]. I did that in previous versions of this proof of concept/pet project and it was dead slow when I started feeding huge numbers. Yes, I used a profiler. No, this wasn't the only slow part of the system, but I wasted a considerable amount of time in this naive lookup/mapping.

The question, finally:

Since I basically just need to remap to the input, I thought about creating a List of hashed values for the list of `ISet<Point>`, doing the same for my result from the processing and therefor avoiding to compare whole sets.

Is this a good idea? Would you call this premature optimization (I know that the naive way above is too slow, but should I implement something less clever first? Performance is really important here, think days of runtime again)? Any other suggestions to ease the burdon here or ideas what I should read up on?

---

Update: Sorry for not providing a better explanation or a sample right away.

Sample for [1] (Note: These are real possible datapoints, but obviously it's limited) :

```
new List<ISet<Point>>() {
  new HashSet() {new Point(0,0) },
  new HashSet() {new Point(0,0), new Point(2,1) },
  new HashSet() {new Point(0,1), new Point(3,1) }
}
```

[2] is just a boolean vector of the length n. For n = 2 it's

- 0,0
- 0,1
- 1,0
- 1,1

I can do that one by using an int or long, basically.

Now I have a function that takes an vector and an `ISet<Point>` and returns a new `ISet<Point>`. It's not a 1:1 transformation: An set of 5 might result in a set of 11 or whatever. The resulting `ISet<Point>` *is* however guaranteed to be part of the input.

Using letters for a set of points and numbers for the bit vectors, I'm starting with this

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

What I need to have at the end is

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F
1 -  C  A  E  -  -
2 B  C  E  F  A  -
3 ................
4 ................
5 ................
6 F  C  B  A  -  - 
7 E  -  C  A  -  D
```

There are several costly operations in these project, one is the preparation of the sets of point ([1]). But this question is about the matching now: I can easily (more or less, not that important now) compute a target ISet for a given bit vector and a source ISet. Now I need to match/find that in the original set.

The whole beast is going to be a state machine, where the set of points is a valid state. Later I don't care about the individual states, I can actually refer to them by anything (a letter, an index, whatever). I just need to keep the associations:

1, B => C

---

Update: Eric asked if a HashSet would be possible. The answer is yes, but only if the dataset stays small enough. My question (hashing) is: Might it be possible/a good idea to employ a hashing algorithm for this hashset? My idea is this:

- Walk the (lazily generated) list/sequence of `ISet<Point>` (I could change this type, I just want to stress that it is a mathematical set of points, no duplicates).

  - Create a simpler representation of the input (a hash?) and store it (in a hashset?)
  - Compute all target sets for this input, but only store again a simple representation (see above)
  - Discard the set
- Fix up the mapping (equal hash = equal state)

Good idea? Problems with this? One that I could come up with is a collision (how probable is that?) - and I wouldn't know a good hashing function to begin with..

Comment: I'm finding it hard to understand the question - could you give a small example of the data involved?

Comment: How huge is huge? Saying "finite" doesn't say much...

Comment: I'm with Jon. I think I sorta see the operations you're trying to perform, but if you have an example with, like, ten numbers in it instead of several thousand, that would help make it clear.

Comment: I'm with Eric here, it sounds like it's easy to answer, if you would give a simple example of what you are trying to do. Aka explain it better ;-)

Comment: Are you building an implementation of the pi calculus? This business of a set of points representing a state in the process of a state machine is sounding very familiar.

Comment: Eric: No, it's a (private time, pet project, do something useful with your brain) automaton that should help with string matching. Someday..

Comment: You can come up with a good hashing algorithm that makes lookups fast, but you will not come up with a 32 bit hash that eliminates collisions. (Coincidentally, the impossibility of doing so is the topic of my blog later this month, see it for details.)

Comment: Re: memory: You've got a million sets of points, each set has about ten points, and each point takes up what, 16 bytes or so? So that's 160 million bytes, which is rather a lot, but doable. However it's probably sensible to think about other techniques for representing this thing, either by keeping most of the data on disk, or by compressing it heavily in memory somehow. What can you tell us about the points? Are they always 2-D? Are they integer pairs, double pairs, what? Do we have any knowledge of how they are distributed in their vector space?

Comment: Looking forward to your blog entry then.. :) The points are always in the 2d space, y is probably not even going to grow above 8? 12? depending on my available computation time I've to draw the line here. x is only useful in {0..2y+1} for me. So we're talking about a fairly limited set. Not sure what I did wrong last time (was a first shot in F#), but I _did_ ending up with OOM exceptions at some point using the naive approach of keeping everything around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I think I understand the problem at least now.  Let me see if I can rephrase.

Let's start by leaving sets out of it.  We'll keep it abstract.

You have a large list L, containing instances of reference type S (for "set").  Such a list is of course logically a mapping from natural numbers N onto S.

```
L: N --> S
```

S has the property that two instances can be compared for both reference equality and value equality. That is, there can be two instances of S which are not reference equals, but logically represent the same value.

You have a function F which takes a value of type V (for "vector") and an instance of type S and produces another instance of type S.

```
F: (V, S) --> S
```

Furthermore, you know that if F is given an instance of S from L then the resulting instance of S will be *value equals* to something on the list, but not necessarily *reference equals*.

The problem you face is: given an instance s of S which is the result of a call to F, which member L(n) is value-equals to s?

Yes?

The naive method -- go down L(1), L(2), ... testing set equality along the way will be dead slow. It'll be at least linear in the size of L.

I can think of several different ways to proceed.  The easiest is your initial thought: make L something other than a list.  Can you make it a `HashSet<S>` instead of `List<S>`?  If you implement a hashing algorithm and equality method on S then you can build a fast lookup table.

If that doesn't suit then we'll explore other options.

UPDATE:

OK, so I can see two basic ways to deal with your memory problem. (1) Keep everything in memory using data structures that are much smaller than your current implementation, or (2) change how you store stuff on disk so that you can store an "index" in memory and rapidly go to the right "page" of the disk file to extract the information you need.

You could be representing a point as a single short where the top byte is x and the bottom byte is y, instead of representing it as two ints; a savings of 75%.

A set of points could be implemented as a sorted array of shorts, which is pretty compact and easy to write a hash algorithm for.

That's probably the approach I'd go for since your data are so compressible.

Comment: First of all: Thanks for taking the time. Yes, you're on the right path: What you rephrase is what I want to do. HashSet: Might be an option, but I had memory issues in the past. If S contains on average 10 points, L consists of 1.000.000 times S.. I guess I need to do a more clever thing. Will update again in a minute.

Comment: Thanks again. Both the "index to a file on disk" and "use a short to represent both coordinates" ideas were very helpful.
"Easy to write a hash algorithm for" is - well - not exactly what I feel when I think about it. I could come up with something, but I would always be afraid of collisions => losing data in my application. Anyway, you wasted a ton of your time on my spare time project, thanks a lot. I'll accept this answer, since it takes me from 10% to 80% for my current problem and I have to figure out the tiny details on my own anyway.

Comment: @Benjamin: You're welcome. But I think you're misunderstanding what a hash code is for.  A hash algorithm is always lossy; its purpose in a hash set is simply to *speed up* the comparison process by enabling you to rapidly identify and reject non-matches. The problem with collisions is that they result in slower lookups, not because they lose data.

Comment: Maybe I was again unable to communicate my train of thoughts: Loss of data, if I would store nothing but the hash of the set of points as a reduced dataset - because that's what I wanted to ask initially (see topic/subject/headline of the question). Collisions would mean that I now have two different sets of point mapped to one value (int, long) -> Bad. A hashset would just have a slightly worse lookup time as far as I know, but if I keep _only_ the hashes around I'd need a stable 1:1 mapping.

Comment: @Benjamin: Right. You're not going to easily get that without collisions. A 100+ bit crypto strength hash would do the trick, but a randomly distributed 32 bit hash code has a 1% chance of collision in the first 9300 hashes and a 99% chance of collision in the first couple hundred thousand hashes. The hashes aren't a substitute for storing the data.